# Is data on international air traffic volume in the US freely available?

Tags: usa, datasets

I'm looking for air traffic flow data which has the passenger air traffic from countries outside of the US to every international airport in the US. Ideally, I would like to know how many passengers came from other countries to the international airports in the US but I can also use load factors. I'm only interested in free data. Any ideas would be appreciated. I'm willing to parse together a data from multiple datasets/sources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [U.S. International Air Passenger and Freight Statistics Report](https://www.transportation.gov/policy/aviation-policy/us-international-air-passenger-and-freight-statistics-report).

Example of data for Q4 2015:

[image]